# Adding spaces in elements of list(PY)

Tags: python

I have a problem:

I have a list that consists of elements of different lenghts:
`det_slopes_JKH = ['Superpipe Bolgen','JatzPark','Avalanch Training Center','Bräma schwer']`

and i would like to add spaces `' '` to the shorter words, with the purpose of having all the elements of the list with the same lenght.

```
det_slopes_JKH2 = []
for element in det_slopes_JKH:
     if len(element) < len(element[2]:
         det_slopes_JKH2.append(element + ' ')
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to add spaces?

Comment: For example len('jatzpark') is 8, while len('Avalanch Training Center') is 24. The result i would like to have is len('jatzpark.. .. ') = 24 ( the dors should be blank spaces)

Comment: @FedericoP. can u show expected output

Comment: the one of Marcin is what i wanted! Thanks to everybody!

Comment: Not that Marcin's one is a bad answer, oh no it's a pretty good one, but imho the answer you want is Domenico's, that uses a faster native string method and is encapsulated in a reusable function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal is not very clear but I am assuming you want to have all the strings of the same length.

This adds a space to each string until all are of the same length (the length of the longest string):

```
def equalize_lengths(l):
    length = len(max(l, key=len))
    return [e.ljust(length) for e in l]
```

Comment: It seems to me that I cannot remember all the string methods... so my answer, very similar to yours, uses formatting. Yours is better. Extra points for encapsulating the stuff in a function.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

1. Length of biggest string using `max = len(max(det_slopes_JKH, key=len))`
2. Append spaces until length is equal to length of biggest string. This can be done using `ljust()` as `i.ljust(max)`. `ljust` keeps adding spaces to right of string until **string length = max**.

This can be done using list comprehension as:

```
>>> det_slopes_JKH = ['Superpipe Bolgen','JatzPark','Avalanch Training Center','Bräma schwer']
>>> [i.ljust(len(max(det_slopes_JKH, key=len))) for i in det_slopes_JKH]
['Superpipe Bolgen        ', 'JatzPark                ', 'Avalanch Training Center', 'Bräma schwer           ']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
det_slopes_JKH = ['Superpipe Bolgen','JatzPark','Avalanch Training Center','Bräma schwer']
max_length  = max(len(elem) for elem in det_slopes_JKH)
det_slopes_JKH2 = [elem + ' '*(max_length - len(elem)) for elem in det_slopes_JKH]
print(det_slopes_JKH2)
```

Result is:

```
['Superpipe Bolgen        ', 'JatzPark                ', 'Avalanch Training Center', 'Bräma schwer            ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use builtin `max` with `key=len` it will give you maximum length string then use `len` to get the length and then use `string formatting`.

```
>>> max(det_slopes_JKH, key=len)
'Avalanch Training Center'
>>> len(max(det_slopes_JKH, key=len)
24
>>> ['{:24}'.format(elem) for elem in det_slopes_JKH]
['Superpipe Bolgen        ', 'JatzPark                ', 'Avalanch Training Center', 'Br\xc3\xa4ma schwer           ']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x.ljust(len(max(det_slopes_JKH,key=len))) for x in det_slopes_JKH ]
```

You can try this one liner.

Comment: `-len(x)` is not needed: ljust argument is the final length of the string, not the amount to pad.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen string formatting in the other answers and I happen to like formatting, that said I couldn't resist to show my 0.02 answer

```
maxlen = max(len(elt) for elt in places)
fmt = "%-"+str(maxlen)+"s"
places = [fmt%elt for elt in places]
```